# Way to avoid SocketException try/catch?

Tags: c#, .net, dns, host

I have been trying to find a way to determine whether or not a string, a hostname, in this example, is indeed a valid hostname and can resolve to an IP. I am using the DNS class in C#, and using the function:

```
Dns.GetHostEntry(hostname)
```

However, if this function fails, it throws a SocketException error, and with the list of strings I must deal with, these exceptions can occur quite often. I created a try/catch seen below to handle this:

```
public List<string> fetchIP(string hostname)
{
    try
    {
        List<string> theIPs = new List<string>();
        IPHostEntry entry = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostname);
        foreach (IPAddress ipAddress in entry.AddressList)
        {
            theIPs.Add(ipAddress.ToString());
        }
        return theIPs;
    }
    catch (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException)
    {
        return null;
    }   
}
```

Now the problem is... This runs very slow. The page currently takes over 10 seconds to load on average, because of the failed `GetHostEntry()` calls. Is there any way to know if a hostname can resolve to an IP without doing it the way I have? I cannot find a way to avoid horrible performance.

Sorry if my question is unclear, this is my first asked on this site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolving a hostname is often a time-consuming process.  To fully resolve a hostname is unavoidably going to bottleneck on the response time of a remote DNS server if the answer isn't already cached.  Your best bet is to either run a local DNS server that would be able to respond immediately (and cache previous requests) or maintain a cache in your code.

Either way, new requests that don't hit the cache will take a long time.  A mitigation would be to pre-populate your DNS server with requests you expect to happen.  How to do this is outside the scope of this question.

Answer (score -1):

Are you running in 4.5?  You could try the Uri.CheckHostName method.

```
Console.WriteLine(Uri.CheckHostName("www.google.com"));
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.checkhostname(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Well drat - now that I read more on it, it doesn't actually DNS lookup the host, just checks for valid format.  :(